# Parke-Taylor formula in the $n=4$ simple case

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, spinors, helicity

I am trying to do ex. 2.23 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697. 
I have chosen as reference spinors $q_1,q_2 = p_3$ and $q_3,q_4 = p_1$.

Therefore if I compute $A^4[1^- 2^- 3^+ 4^+]$ the computation is reduced to

$$A^4[1^- 2^- 3^+ 4^+] = \alpha \ (p_2 \cdot \ \epsilon_1^-) (\epsilon_2^- \cdot \ \epsilon_4^+) (p_4 \cdot \ \epsilon_3^+)\tag{*}$$

Where $\alpha$ is an irrelevant power of -2.
The problem is that carrying on the computation from here, one obtains:

$$A^4[1^- 2^- 3^+ 4^+] = PT \times (p_1 \cdot \ p_4)/(p_1 \cdot \ p_3)$$

Where $PT$ is the right term of the Parke-Taylor formula, so it should be 
$(p_1 \cdot \ p_3)=(p_1 \cdot \ p_4)$. But that does not seem right to me.

Moreover if I instead choose as reference spinors $q_1,q_2 = p_3$ i get the right result.

I have found online the explicit computation in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9601359, eq (40). There the choice $q_1,q_2 = p_4$ is done, but it is quick to see that by choosing $q_1,q_2 = p_3$ one arrives at $(*)$ and from there to my result as written below.

Now, assuming I have made no mistake (and surely I must had), this seems to mean that it is not possible to arbitrarly choose the reference spinors, i.e. gauge invariance is violated.

Could you help me spot the likely mistake? Have I forgotten some Feynman diagram? Or maybe it is not possible to make that choice of spinors?

---

For completeness, I write here how I obtain my final result from (*).

$$(*) = \alpha (\frac{\langle 12 \rangle[23]}{[31]})(\frac{\langle 21 \rangle [34]}{[32]\langle 14 \rangle})(\frac{\langle 14 \rangle [43]}{\langle 13 \rangle})(\frac{1}{\langle 12 \rangle [12]}) = 
\alpha (\frac{ \langle 12 \rangle}{[31]})(\frac{\langle 21 \rangle [34]}{\langle 14 \rangle})(\frac{\langle 12 \rangle [23]}{\langle 13 \rangle})(\frac{1}{\langle 12 \rangle [12]}) =
 \alpha (\frac{\langle 12 \rangle^3}{\langle 12 \rangle \langle 14 \rangle})(\frac{[23][34]}{\langle 13 \rangle [31] [12]}) (\frac{\langle 23 \rangle \langle 34\rangle \langle 12 \rangle}{\langle 23 \rangle \langle 34\rangle \langle 12 \rangle})$$

until now I have just used momentum conservation to say $⟨14⟩[43]= -⟨12⟩[23]$,antisimmetry of $⟨.⟩$ and $[.]$ to simplify some factors and I wrote $1 = \frac{a}{a}$ in the last line.

Now, rearranging various factors, and by writing $⟨ij⟩[ij]= 2(p_i \dot \ p_j)$ one obtains

$$...= α(\frac{\langle 12 \rangle^4}{\langle 12 \rangle \langle 23 \rangle \langle 34 \rangle \langle 41 \rangle}) (p_1 \dot \ p_4)/(p_1 \dot \ p_3)$$

I have been a little sloppy in absorbing all signs and $(\sqrt{2})^n$ factors in $\alpha$ but that should not be the problem.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? We explicitly (by policy) exclude "check my work for me" type questions, but I think with a little editing this could be an interesting one.

Comment: Well I was hoping that someone would simply tell me "hey dude, you can't choose those as reference spinors because ..." or "actually, your answer is correct, since ... = 1". Or even "you forgot a Feynman diagram, you n00b!"

Otherwise this seems to be a violation of the free choice of the reference spinors, i.e. gauge invariance...

Comment: Ok I've finally found the mistake: there was another Feynman (14 -> 23) diagram contributing, now the result is correct.